# Open a Form if there is not another instance of it Open - Pass Type to a Method

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I want to simplify some of my code. Therefore I want to make a function which checks, if a certain form is already open. Right now I have the code below behind every button on my start-form.

```csh
private void button_parts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
    foreach (Form frm in fc)
    {
        if (frm is frm_parts) { return; }
    }
    frm_Teile newForm = new frm_parts();
    newForm.Show();
}
```

Now I would like to have something like:

```
private void button_parts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartNewForm(frm_parts);
}

private void StartNewForm(Type myForm)
{
    FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
    foreach (Form frm in fc)
    {
        if (frm is myForm) { return; }
    }
    myForm newForm = new myForm();
    newForm.Show();
}
```

***But I cannot pass a type to a function***
EDIT: You certainly can, but I didn't know how and where to start.

Is there a(nother) way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either of these options.

Using a generic method:

```
private void StartNewForm<T>()
    where T : Form, new()
{
    FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
    foreach (Form frm in fc)
    {
        if (frm is T) { return; }
    }
    var newForm = new T();
    newForm.Show();
}
```

Here is the usage: `StartNewForm<Form1>();`

Create your form using `Activator.CreateInstance`

```
private void StartNewForm(Type myForm)
{
    FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
    foreach (Form frm in fc)
    {
        if (frm.GetType() == myForm) { return; }
    }
    var newForm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(myForm);
    newForm.Show();
}
```

Here is the usage: `StartNewForm(typeof(Form1));`

**Note:**

- The non-generic version is here just because you thought you can't do it using `Type`. But you should know the better option is using generic version because it performs type checking at compile time while in the non-generic version you should perform some validations, for example you should check if `myForm` is of type of `Form`.
- I didn't change your code, but for example you can do it this way:

  ```
  private void StartNewForm<T>() where T : Form, new()
  {
      var f = (Application.OpenForms.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault() ?? new T());
      f.Show();
  }
  ```

Comment: @PeterBons The usage examples which I added show how to use generic method or pas type.

Comment: Thank you! Both work perfectly. Is there a prefered way to do it? Are there any downsides to those sollutions?

Comment: I personally prefer using generic way. It is typed while the other method needs more validations to check if `myForm` is actually is a `Form`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei you're absolutely right, my bad. did not read all obviously. I stand corrected :-)

Comment: @PeterBons No problem :)

Comment: Yeah, *always* prefer the generic method when you can use it. Don't push off to run-time what can be verified at compile-time. Not only do you get a performance boost, but more importantly, you ensure correctness.

Comment: @Diego Read also **Notes**.

Comment: Just did. Had to google the two ?? :D Great idea an i guess much more efficient. I will read up on generic methods. Just starting out with C#. Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome. The [?? operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

Comment: Wheeee, me again: Is there a way to access the form (and controls of it) when using the generic method? Or do i have to wirte the line `var f = (Application.OpenForms.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault() ?? new T());` again and then write something like `f.textbox.text = "abc"`

Comment: When you are working with generic method (also with non-generic version) you can not say `f.textBox1` in method, because the only thing which we know about f, is: it's of type of `Form` and it has a parameter-less constructor. So `f.textBox1` is invalid.

Comment: Think about a situation when you passed a form which doesn't have a `textBox1` property. Then an exception will throw. There are multiple solutions if you really need to use `textBox1`, for example you can check its existence or you can have an interface implementing a method to access `textBox1` and then add a generic constraint to restrict `T` to be of type of your interface.

Answer (score 0):

Improvements over previous answer:

- You should implement some kind of interface and check if the form should or shouldnt be open more than once. Also you can set more properties if needed. *IOnlyOnceForm* or something like that.
- Consider having a base class for all of the forms you want to control. This way you can, for example, just .Show() them and continue the method or abort it and pop up the current open instance of that type. *MySuperDuperAppFormBase* (you are free to choose a better name!)
- Also check with Application.OpenForms.OfType instead of the forearch.