# C# duplicate open form code redundancy

Tags: c#, winforms

I got a code to open my forms without any duplication, but i want to create a method for this, to avoid code redundancy.

My code :

```
    private void form1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Form openForm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (openForm.GetType() == typeof(form1))
            {
                openForm.Activate();
                return;
            }
        }

        form1 f1 = new form1();
        f1.MdiParent = this;
        if (!f1.IsDisposed)
            f1.Show();
    }
```

What i want to:

```
public void formOpener(Form form, string formName)
{
    foreach (Form openForm in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (openForm.GetType() == typeof(form))
        {
            openForm.Activate();
            return;
        }
    }

    form formName = new form();
    formName.MdiParent = this;
    if (!formName.IsDisposed)
        formName.Show();
}

private void form1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formOpener(form1);
}
```

I have some issues with the parameters.
Thanks for any answer!

Comment: what issues do you have

Comment: You have a string parameter formName and you declare a Form local variable called formName too.

Comment: is your form-class really called `form`? This is a bad name according the conventions and might cause some issues, in particular as you´ve also a method-paramater called `form`.

Comment: my form classes not called form its just for the sample.

Comment: i have two error messages: ''form' is a variable but is used like a type' and 'A local or parameter named cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter'

Comment: Then you probably need `openForm.GetType() == form.GetType()`.

Comment: [Open a Form if there is not another instance of it Open - Pass Type to a Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512074/open-a-form-if-there-is-not-another-instance-of-it-open-pass-type-to-a-method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like that?:

```
public void formOpener<T>() where T : Form, new()
{
    var openedForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();

    if (openedForm != null)
    {
        openedForm.Activate();
        return;
    }

    T newForm = new T();
    newForm.MdiParent = this;
    newForm.Show();
}
```

`OfType<T>` extension method requires `using System.Linq;`

Usage

```
formOpener<Form1>();
```

This will show the form if there is any open. Otherwise, will create new one.

If you can have multiple forms of type T open, then use `Name` property to distinguish them.

```
public void formOpener<T>(string formName) where T : Form, new()
{
    var openedForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<T>()
        .Where(x => x.Name == formName).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: It finds form that can be cast to T, that may not be what You expect in all cases.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek I see, the OP seems to have only one at a time. *Edit:* Included solution for that case

Comment: Thanks for your perfect answer!