# C# win forms create form child using custom method

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I want to create form childs using custom form helper method. 
My idea is to avoid duplicate code for showing all childs. So i create form helper class whitch will render passed form.
Am realy new in c# and my code does not work.

What i try:

```
class FormHelper : Form
{

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// Render form child form
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="form"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Form Render(Form form)
    {
        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (f.GetType() == typeof(form))
            {
                f.Activate();
                return;
            }
        }
        form = new Form();
        form.MdiParent = this;
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

In parent form i call this:

```
private void unosGrupeArtikalaBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Core.FormHelper.Render(this, new UnosGrupeArtikala());
}
```

After than i get blank and empty form(no title, no content, etc...).

How create this to work ? Maybie to use generic form types ?

Comment: You need to use a generic method or pass the form type to the method [like this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512074/open-a-form-if-there-is-not-another-instance-of-it-open-pass-type-to-a-method).

Comment: Right, this post slove my problem! Thanks