# Best way to check whether a form is already opened?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a program that has a function like this:

- If form *soanthao* is opened, then the program will add a new tab page into tabControlEx control of soanthao form
- If form *soanthao* is not opened, the program will load soanthao form first, then the program will add a new tab page into tabControlEx control of soanthao form.

It should be noted that the tabControlEx control has no tab pages.

I've used this code:

```
soanthao st = new soanthao();
            bool opened=false;
            FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

            foreach (Form frm in fc)
            {
                if (st == frm)
                {
                     opened = true;
                }
            }
            if (opened==false)
            {

                RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
                TabPage tb = new TabPage();
                tb.Text = textBox1.Text;
                st.tabControlEx1.TabPages.Add(tb);
                rtb.Parent = tb;
                rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                st.Show();
                this.Hide();
                opened = false;
            }
            if (opened == true)
            {

                RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
                TabPage tb = new TabPage();
                tb.Text = textBox1.Text;
                st.tabControlEx1.TabPages.Add(tb);
                st.tabControlEx1.SelectTab(st.tabControlEx1.TabCount - 1);
                rtb.Parent = tb;
                rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                this.Hide();
            }
```

But the problem is the program always open a new soanthao form, even when soanthao form is opened already.

Comment: You might want to consider collapsing those long `if` blocks - most of the code inside looks identical and/or safe even if redundant - e.g. you should be able to call `Show` on the form even if its already shown and `SelectTab` even if there's only a single tab.

Comment: [Open a Form if there is not another instance of it Open - Pass Type to a Method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37512074/3110834)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using *Linq*; if you want to find out if `soanthao` has been opened:

```
using System.Linq;

... 

soanthao st = Application
  .OpenForms
  .OfType<soanthao>()
  .LastOrDefault(); // If many soanthao are opened, take the last one

if (st != null) {
  // "st" is the soanthao instance opened
}
else {
  // no opened soanthao instance, let's create it
  st = new soanthao();

  ...

  // ...and show up
  st.Show(); 
}
```

The error in your approach is in the `st == frm` line:

```
foreach (Form frm in fc)
{
    // You actually check if "st" instance is opened and it's not, but created only
    if (st == frm) // <- Error is here
    {
        opened = true;
    }
}
```

To amend your approach:

```
bool opened = false;

foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms) {
  // Do we have ANY soanthao form opened?
  if (frm is soanthao) { // ... i.e. if an opened form is of type soanthao?
    opened = true;
    break;
  } 
} 

...
```

Comment: It won't open new form now, but the problem is now the program doesn't add new tab page to soanthao form

Comment: @TùngVương - make sure that you're using `form` now rather than `st`. The first step after discovering that it's null (and so no such form was opened) is to *then* set `form = new soanthao();`

Comment: Can you explain more, I don't really understand what you mean