# Control one form that is opened multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I have the same form opened **multiple times** but I want to control **just one of them** (*one that f.e has "hello" as window title (text)* <- to identify)

How do I manage to do that?

EDIT:
Here is an example of what I want to do (it's a bit complicated, im not good at explaining what I want)

```
private void openthesecformfirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 sec = new Form2();
    sec.Text = "Hi";
    sec.Show();
    //The second form is now opened
}

private void openthesecformsecond_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 sec = new Form2();
    sec.Text = "Hello";
    sec.Show();
    //the second form is now opened twice
}

private void changelabelinfirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Identified by the title the first opened form2 is supposed to change a label text

    //How do I get this one specifically?
}

private void changelabelinsecond_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Identified by the title the second opened form2 is supposed to change a label text

    //How do I get this one specifically?
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Why not holding a reference from where you open the forms?

Comment: Do you just open the forms and let go of the references? Or do oyu have them in a list? If you have them in a List or similar, you cna use Linq to find a specific one.

Comment: You should retain a reference to each form you open and use that to update the text. You could use two field-level variables or a list or a dictionary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37512122/3110834

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [Application.OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netframework-4.7.2) property.

Answer (score 1):

For find window in OS Windows you can use `FindWindowEx` from the Win32 Api, for example:

1. Because this is original unsafe code you should import functions from user32.dll:

   ```
   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)] static extern IntPtr 
   FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, 
   string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr 
   childAfter, 
   string className,  string windowTitle);
   ```
2. After import you can use function like that:

   ```
    var CaptionTextForLooking = "hello"; // or "Hi"

    var foundWindowPtr = 
    FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero,CaptionTextForLooking 
    ,IntPtr.Zero);
   ```

More you can find [here](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.FindWindow)